# With Electromagnets, would pulsing the current going through have the same effect as reducing the current?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a project where I need to decrease the strength of an electromagnet and in my case it would be easier to pulse the current (on and off), so if it would work that would be ideal.

thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the electromagnet? Running an electromagnet on pulsating or alternating current has some important differences to running it on constant direct current.

Comment: ...in particular, any practical electromagnet will act rather strongly as an _[inductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor)_, and starting and stopping the current in an inductor is not a trivial thing to do.

Comment: P.S., Electronic engineers call what you propose _[pulse width modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation#Power_delivery)_, and circuits that do it (even for inductive loads) are practical, but they're tricky to get right---not beginner projects.